# I can't find Runner/Runner directory in Flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter

After creating a new Flutter project I can't find the Runner/Runner directory that is described in this documentation under step 3b - https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#configure_an_ios_app

I am trying to add the file GoogleService-Info.plist to my project to configure an ios app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you open your project in Xcode by opening your_project/ios/Runner.xcodeproj there should be a Runner folder inside another Runner folder. Right click the Runner folder that is inside the other Runner folder and click 'Add Files to "Runner"...'. Add the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ios/Runner/Runner folder, and you don't have to create it.

You have to copy the file to ios/Runner folder, but then you have to use XCode to add the file to the workspace.

[XCode workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMjrm.png)

1. Copy the file to ios/Runner
2. Open "Runner.xcworkspace" with XCode
3. Select "Runner" folder
4. Right-click, "Add files to Runner..." and select the GoogleService-Info.plist
5. Close XCode and "flutter run" again

Answer (score 0):

You're missing Flutter SDK. You need to configure FlutterSDK path:

1. Download Flutter SDK: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows
2. Config in Android Studio: File -> Setting -> Language & Frameworks -> Flutter -> Add Flutter SDK path

Answer (score -1):

After creating your project with `flutter create`, the Runner directory will be in:

```
<your app project directory>/ios/Runner
```

This is the root folder of your iOS code, and is probably where the Firebase tutorial is telling you to put the file. If you want, you can create a new "Runner" directory inside of it and put the file there.