# Unable to find a target named `Runner` in project `Runner.xcodeproj` did find `dev` and `prod`

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am completely new to Flutter.

I was given a project that had been developed a few months before (December 2020) on Visual Studio Code with Flutter and Dart in order to deploy it on the [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)).

I would like to point out that the project was working very well at that time, and a test version had even been deployed on iPhones.

I have to make sure that it works locally, and then I'm going to deploy it to the App Store.

So I opened the source code of the project in my Visual Studio Code. I tried to compile it, but it didn't work. I don't know if when you open the source code of a project; there are specific configurations to do.

I'm not sure if there are any specific configurations to be made when opening source code for a project, but after browsing the forum, I realized that the error must have come from the most recent version of my Flutter, and that's not the version the application was developed with.

So I followed the instructions coming from this solution in *[Flutter iOS build failed an error of pod files: Podfile is out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362862/flutter-ios-build-failed-an-error-of-pod-files-podfile-is-out-of-date)* and *[Flutter error: Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String. I’ve searched through discussions, but I can’t seem to fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516334/flutter-error-invalid-podfile-file-no-implicit-conversion-of-nil-into-string)* to generate my podfiles again. Except that now this error is generated at compile time:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,674ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
    [!] Unable to find a target named `Runner` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did
    find `dev` and `prod`.
```

How can I fix this?

My previous pod file was

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  # Flutter Pod

  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers machines .
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

target 'prod' do
  # Flutter Pod

  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

And the new created one looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

And actually when I run `flutter doctor`, I get:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

And actually opening my project in Xcode gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Did you open it in xCode first?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467284/i-cant-find-runner-runner-directory-in-flutter-project can help you.

Comment: can you please specify the previous flutter version, current version and then run `flutter doctor` and share the output in here ?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad i though i was suppose to use it when tryin to publish the app on the appstore... i don t really know how it works

Comment: @AlexanderDischberg I modify my post to have enough space for pasting my pod files

Answer (score 125):

It is kind of a bug. The RunnerTests is supposed to be added manually,. but somehow the command added it automatically. It can refer to the RunnerTests in *[iOS Device Testing](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/main/packages/integration_test#ios-device-testing)*

But to solve this, open `Podfile` and comment the lines:

```
  # target 'RunnerTests' do
  #   inherit! :search_paths
  # end
```

Comment: This works! Kudos!

Comment: It took me the whole day to find a solution for this problem. Well, I reset my Mac today cause something messed up. But these three #'s solved the problem after multiple hours trying to fix it. <3

Comment: WOW... this worked!! After flutter_fire_cli configuration, I got this error on ios and got a gradle error on android. What would be the equivalent solution for android??

Comment: This is so messed up. I mean thank you, but this is really horrible developer experience @flutter.

Comment: it worked for me, but I don't understand the meaining

Comment: This fixed my issue just now. Thank you.

Answer (score 35):

I faced this issue.

> Unable to find a target named `Runner Tests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`

I had to delete my ios folder (`Not recommended if you have done any changes to native IOS code`) and then recreated it using this command.

If you have made any changes in the `IOS` folder, try this commend without removing the `ios` directory. This should generate the missing elements.

```
flutter create --platform ios .
```

**Probable Cause**

I have noticed this issue in the projects that are created on an OS other than `mac`.

Comment: I upgraded flutter version from 2.x to 3.x. Then the build started to fail. Recreating the iOS solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have used Flutter 1.X previously.

So here is what I did when I recently downloaded Flutter v2.0.4:

1. when I first open my old project, Visual Studio Code will show all my files contain errors. So what I do is to run `flutter pub get`. This will get rid of the error.
2. Next I try to run in debug mode in the iOS simulator. After that, I open up the `ios` (inside the project) folder with Xcode, click on *Runner* under 'targets` and check the signing before I test it on my iPhone.

So in your case, discard any changes that you recently made or stash it with Git if you need it first. And run `flutter pub get` and test it on simulator. This should fix the issue, and they apply/pop your stash back and now you are good to go.

Also note that whenever you run `flutter clean`, you have to run `flutter pub get` again. Else you will see Visual Studio Code will show all your files in the library folder in red.

Run this if `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` doesn't do the job properly:

```s
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
rm Podfile
pod setup
flutter build ios
```

Comment: i try it , but i got this error , supposing there is a still a problem with my podfile 
`
Running pod install...                                           1,940ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳

    [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

     #  from /Users/vanessa/Documents/VSProjects/Teichmann-master-org/ios/Podfile:54
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #      unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
     >        FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'),
     copied_flutter_dir)
     #      end
`

Comment: @Reims okay i added some additional steps that i record when i update my flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the external/added Target from the podfile rather than the main app name.

Like in case of Flutter I'm using AgoraRtc and added the broadcast in the target for screen sharing and I just comment down and Works fine now!

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  # use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  use_modular_headers!

  # pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  # target 'RunnerTests' do
  #   inherit! :search_paths
  # end
  # target 'flutterbroadcastscreen' do
  #   use_frameworks!

  #   # use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  #   use_modular_headers!
  
  #   pod 'AgoraRtcEngine_iOS', '4.2.6'
  # end
end
```